# Real time chat in jetpack compose

Tags: android

I'm stuck. I need help. I am currently developing an Android application. I'm trying to do a real-time chat with FCM, but I am stuck regarding chat security and privacy. Someone help me, please.

I've been researching, but I get too many things, and the only thing I manage to do is confuse myself more. If someone could give me a hand, I would appreciate it. Save me!

Comment: You need to ask a much more specific question.  This is too vague to answer.